# Error: expected identifier before ')' token

Tags: c++, random

Estoy haciendo un juego donde el usuario lanza una moneda y el programa le muestra las veces que salió cara y las que salió cruz. Dejo el código de la clase Moneda, donde me tira el error.

```
 class Moneda //Moneda.h
{
private:
    int cara;
    int cruz;
    int r;
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL)); //Línea del error

public:
    Moneda();
    void Lanzar();
    int Resultado();
};

Moneda::Moneda()
{
    this->cara = 0;
    this->cruz = 0;
}

void Moneda::Lanzar()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        r = Resultado();
        std::cout << r << std::endl;

        if(r == 1)
        {
            this->cruz++;
        }
        else
        {
            this->cara++;
        }
    }
}

int Moneda::Resultado()
{
    return (1 + rand() % 6);
}
```

El lanzamiento de la moneda es random, y cada vez que se lanza, imprime por pantalla un 1 si es cara y un 0 si es cruz en un total de 10 veces como máximo (un lanzamiento es una salida por pantalla representada con un 0 o un 1 según corresponda).
En la misma línea, me tira el error

> `expected ',' or '...' before time`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `srand` tiene que ir en el `main`. En las clases, ya sea en la sección `private` o `public` solo pueden ir funciones, por ejemplo `void`.

Ten en cuenta que el resultado depende del *timestamp*, que es una cantidad de segundos del reloj del sistema... Si el programa se ejecuta varias veces en el mismo segundo dará el mismo resultado.

Esto se puede notar mejor si quito el `std::endl`:

```
6613256543[arteze@arteze Release]$ ./unexpected
4463632334[arteze@arteze Release]$ ./unexpected
2411456624[arteze@arteze Release]$ ./unexpected
2411456624[arteze@arteze Release]$ ./unexpected
2411456624[arteze@arteze Release]$ ./unexpected
```

Ejemplo de uso:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

class Moneda
{
    private:
        int cara;
        int cruz;
        int r;

    public:
        Moneda(){
            this->cara = 0;
            this->cruz = 0;
        };
        void Lanzar(){
            for( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
            {
                r = Resultado();
                std::cout << r ;

                if( r==1 )
                {
                    this->cruz++;
                }
                else
                {
                    this->cara++;
                }
            }
        };
        int Resultado(){
            return (1 + rand() % 6);
        }
};

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL)); // Ya no sale error.
    Moneda moneda;
    moneda.Lanzar();
    return 0;
}
```